# installing PyQt 5 on windows 7 with python 3.4

Tags: python, pyqt

I wanna install PyQt5 on windows by pip but rise me this error:

```
pip install PyQt5
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.7.1-5.7.1-cp34.cp35.cp36.cp37-none-win32.whl
Collecting sip>=4.19 (from PyQt5)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip>=4.19 (from PyQt5)
 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sip>=4.19 (from PyQt5)
```

and when i try to install sip via pip raise me this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SIP (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for SIP
```

what can i do?

Comment: did you try to install Windows 7 binaries from SourceForge ? There is a x32 or x64 version : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.6/

Comment: PyQt5 wheels only support Python 3.5 or later. So you cannot install the latest PyQt5 using pip with Python 3.4.

Comment: @SyedElec yeah it's work

Answer (score 1):

You can use pip to install SIP and then pyQt5.

```
pip install SIP
```

But in order to be able to do that you need python 3.5 and its better to use virtualenv to not mess with core installation/change version.

Then you can try installing PyQt5.

```
pip install pyqt5
```

Answer (score -1):

- Make sure you have the latest python installed (or at least v3.5)
- Make sure your new python install is being used from your path instead of the old one (`python --version`)
- `pip3 install PyQt5` should then successfully install SIP and PyQt5 for you

Comment: The questionair asks about python 3.4. Your answer implies it's not possible to install PyQt for python 3.4. Is that in fact the case?

Comment: See the comment to the question above: "PyQt5 wheels only support Python 3.5 or later. So you cannot install the latest PyQt5 using pip with Python 3.4. – ekhumoro"